# Java define method parameter as a subtype

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, wildcard, implementation

### What I want to do

I have an interface called `strategy` that has one method `strategise`. This method takes an interface called `Entity` as a parameter.

```
public interface Strategy{

  void strategise(Entity entity);

}
```

```
public interface Entity {
   void do_something();
}
```

I have a class called `EntityImpl` that implements `Entity`. `EntityImpl` has an additional methods that `Entity` does not.

```
public class EntityImpl implements Entity{
    
    void do_something()         // defined in Entity interface
    void do_something_else()    // unique to Person

}
```

I have another class `StrategyImpl` that implements `strategy`.

- `StrategyImpl` expects a `EntityImpl` object to be passed as the parameter to the function it implements from `Strategy` : `strategise`.
- This is because `StrategyImpl.strategise()` calls the method unique to `EntityImpl` which is not defined in `Entity` : `do_something_else()`.

```
public class StrategyImpl implements Strategy {

  void strategise(Entity entity){
       entity.do_something_else();
  }
}
```

[image]

### What I have tried to do

1. If I use the code above, it won't work as `entity.do_something_else()` can't be found as `do_something_else` is unique to `EntityImpl` and not defined in `Entity`.

```
public class StrategyImpl Strategy{

  void strategise(Entity entity){
       entity.do_something_else();
  }
}
```

2. I've tried using a `EntityImpl` object instead of an `Entity` object as the parameter definition in `StrategyImpl.strategise()` but this doesn't work as it thinks I'm not implementing `Entity.strategise()`

```
public class StrategyImpl Strategy{

  void strategise(EntityImpl entity){
       EntityImpl.do_something_else();
  }
}
```

3. I've tried using generics and wildcards, but I'm not familiar with java.

```
public interface Strategy {

   void strategise((E implements Entity) entity);

}
```

### Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Though you did not say this, but I'm guessing you are trying to put all the strategies in a collection or something?

Comment: Nup. It's just that each entity object has a unique strategy object. But the strategies have many common methods.

Comment: This sounds like it's exactly the case for generics: `<E extends Entity>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your design is a little flawed, because what if I did this?

```
Strategy s = new StrategyImpl();
s.strategise(new SomeOtherEntity());
```

This should compile, since `s.strategise` accepts an `Entity` and `SomeOtherEntity` *is* an `Entity`. But eventually it's `StrategyImpl.strategise` that's going to be run. It can only handle `EntityImpl` objects, not `SomeOtherEntity`!

You can solve this problem by adding a generic parameter to `Strategy`:

```
interface Strategy<T extends Entity>{

    void strategise(T entity);

}

class StrategyImpl implements Strategy<EntityImpl>{

    public void strategise(EntityImpl entity){
        entity.do_something_else();
    }
}
```

This way, a `Strategy<EntityImpl>` is a *different type* from a `Strategy<SomeOtherEntity>`.

This restricts you from doing a bunch of things (that you should not do anyway), such as putting a bunch of general `Strategy`s in a collection. Who knows what kind of `Entity` that particular `Strategy` accepts when you take a `Strategy` out of that collection?

You can, however, create a collection of `Strategy<? super X>` where `X` is an type of `Entity`. This collection can then contain `Strategy<AnySuperClassOfX>`. This works because pf [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: Thank you very much! If it's not too much trouble, I was wondering if you could tell me if this design is a good idea based on the fact there is only 1 instance (among 6) of strategy that has that extra function. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

> `StrategyImpl` expects a `EntityImpl` object to be passed as the parameter to the function it implements from Strategy : strategise.

That's a big problem.

Your `StrategyImpl` class implements `Strategy`, and that implies that StrategyImpl fulfills the stated contract, which includes the notion that it has an implementation for the `void strategise(Entity)` method.

But, you don't have that. All you have is an implementation for `void strategise(EntityImpl)`, and if you're fed an Entity that isn't an EntityImpl, all you can do is give up, and crash. That makes your StrategyImpl a thing that shouldn't be `implements Strategy`. It's writing a cheque it can't cash.

The rest of your problems stem from this fundamental design wart. You can work around it (such as the other answer, which will silently do nothing if you pass a non-`EntityImpl` `Entity` object, which seems like an incredibly stupid thing to. At the very least throw something!

But, there's a solution.

One simple solution could be: Well, doctor, it hurts when I press here! - So stop pressing there. If you're just making interfaces because you read in some book or heard from somebody that this is a good idea, well, it isn't. Stop doing it. delete your interfaces, rename your `StrategyImpl` class to `Strategy` and your `EntityImpl` class to `Entity` and just move on. You may think: "But, no! Now I can't choose other implementations later on!" - but we can already tell that is a false choice: You already can't. Your `StrategyImpl` class will fail (silently! Those are really bad bugs as they are hard to find!) if you ever mess around with having any other implementation if `Entity` other than `EntityImpl`, so your convoluted interfaces+classes mess can't deal with it either.

If you really do have a point to this interface+class mess you've made, there is still a solution. You need for the `implements Strategy` part of your type declaration to be more specific. You want to say: I implement a specific sort of Strategy: The kind that can only deal with `EntityImpl` objects. You can do that, too, with generics:

```
public interface Strategy<E extends Entity> {
    public void strategise(E entity);
}
```

And now you can implement your StrategyImpl class:

```
public class StrategyImpl implements Strategy<EntityImpl> {
    public void strategise(EntityImpl entity) {
        // feel free to call .doSomethingElse() here
    }
}
```

It is now in fact impossible for some code that has a `Strategy` variable to just call `strategise(x)` on it, where x is any random Entity. Nope; the generics have to match up. Which is exactly what you want: The compiler will check for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! If it's not too much trouble, I was wondering if you could tell me if this design is a good idea based on the fact there is only 1 instance (among 6) of strategy that has that extra function. What should I do?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about what these things represent, and why there is a 'StrategyImpl' and an 'EntityImpl' (Impl is a code smell), and what another implementation of Entity and/or Strategy might look like.